# Many-to-Many through association Build/Create properties in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The following classes associate with each other (first rails app without a tutorial):

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_users, :class_name => "TeamUser"
  has_many :users, :through => :team_users
end

class TeamUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_users, :class_name => "TeamUser"
  has_many :teams, :through => :team_users
end
```

If I have user attribute, when trying to do the following:

```
u.teams.build(:name => "catsteam", :captain => true, :owner => :true)
```

Captain and Owner are properties of the TeamUser class. Executing the command I get the following:

```
u.teams.build(:name => "catsteam", :captain => true, :owner => :true)
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: captain
...
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

On a side note if I get the user, create the team, then create the teamuser all works. I am so confused and have searched but cannot find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u.teams`refers to `Team` instances. With this command you are building `Team` instances so it is no surprise that captain and owner are not recognized as they are attributes of `TeamUser` and not user. 
You should do this in 2 steps:

```
team = Team.create
team_user = u.team_users.build(:team_id => team.id)
```

Of course if you encounter a validation error on your `team_user`you might want to destroy your team depending on your application.

Comment: That seems a little not good to me. Essentially you are going to the database instead of going once. I thought that since the Models are linked that it should be able to build the proper properties and create TeamUser.

Comment: It might be possible to create the object like you are doing, but certainly not by passing the `:captain` and `:owner` attributes which  belongs to the team user model.

Comment: You would be creating a team user implicitly. How do you expect rails to guess that you are referring to attributes of an instance you are creating implicitly (`TeamUSer` while you are explicitly creating another instance `Team` ?