# Rails 3: Has_many through and Me

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I'm fairly new to Rails, I got this code working but I think I'm preventing it from doing it some of its Rails magic:

**Goal**: Create a `cause` and have the creator become a member via the `build` method and the `has_many :through` association in the `Cause_User_Membership` table.

**Question**: I've gotten it to work, by creating a `cause` and then creating a membership 'manually.' Is there a way for the `Cause_User_Membership` relationship to be created automatically on the creation of a `cause`?

**Cause_Controller.rb**

```
def create
@cause = current_user.causes.build(params[:cause].merge :created_by => current_user.id)

respond_to do |format|
  if @cause.save 
    @membership = current_user.cause_user_memberships.build(:cause_id => @cause.id)
    @membership.save
    format.json { render :json => {current_user: current_user, results: @cause}}
  else
    format.json { render :json => {Message: "You messed up"}}
  end
end
end
```

**User.rb (snippet)**

```
has_many :cause_user_memberships
has_many :causes, :through => :cause_user_memberships
```

**Cause.rb**

```
attr_accessible :title, :location, :description,...
has_many :cause_user_memberships
has_many :users, :through => :cause_user_memberships
```

**Cause_User_Membership.rb** (<--probably not my best model name)

```
    # == Schema Information
#
# Table name: cause_user_memberships
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer          not null
#  cause_id   :integer          not null
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class CauseUserMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cause_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user #, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id" 
  belongs_to :cause #, :class_name => "Cause", :foreign_key => "cause_id"

end
```

Comment: What if you just remove the two lines where you set the `@membership`? I think that record should be created automatically when you use `build` on the association.

Comment: It doesn't create it, that's what has be banging my head against a wall :) Thanks for getting back to me!

Comment: Oh, you're right: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3600-has_many-through-associationbuild-doesnt-create-the-through-models https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/220-habtm-collection-build-doesn-t-build-join-associations-unlike-collection-create

Comment: Thanks for the links, all the info seems to be pre-Rails 3 though. Has anyone seen something more recent about how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: If nobody else answers I'll have a look later today.

Comment: Thank you, I've spent an embarrassing amount of time on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

I found a slightly more "magical" way to do this using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for). First, add a line to your `CauseUserMembership` model:

```
class CauseUserMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cause_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :cause 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cause
```

With that change, you can do this:

```
def create
  @membership = current_user.memberships.build
  @membership.cause = Cause.new(params[:cause].merge(:created_by => current_user.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @membership.save
      ...
```

Because you have told rails to accept nested attributes for the `cause` association on `CauseUserMembership`, it will save the new cause you assigned to `@membership.cause` when it saves the membership itself. So you can save both the cause and membership records at one time, rather than separately.

**Original answer:**

I think what you've done is pretty much the right way to do this. It can be simplified a tad bit: you don't need to build `cause` from `current_user`, you can just use `new` (the `:through` associations on `cause` and `current_user` are set when you create `@membership`).

So like this (I only changed the first line in `create`):

```
def create
  @cause = Cause.new(params[:cause].merge(:created_by => current_user.id))

  respond_to do |format|
    if @cause.save
      @membership = current_user.cause_user_memberships.build(:cause_id => @cause.id)
      @membership.save
      ...
```

See also: [Many-to-Many through association Build/Create properties in Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432343/many-to-many-through-association-build-create-properties-in-rails-app)

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a particular reason why this isn't done 'magically'?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a slightly more "magical" way to do this. See what you think.

Comment: Thank you, the new way worked also. I tried doing almost the same, Cause accepting attributes for memberships, but couldn't get it to work. Of the two approaches you listed, Which would be considered better practice?

Comment: Neither is really better, they're just a bit different. With `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you can update other attributes on the associated record (in this case, `@membership.cause`) through the parent (`@membership`), which may or may not be useful. For example, you could have a form with a membership and nested data for the associated cause, and update that associated data through the membership with just `@membership.update_attributes(params[:membership])`.